# Laravel Migration Remove a table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table previously created with laravel migrations

Now I realise that I don't need that table.

Can I rollback only for that table (this is a migration file just for that table)?

The next time I will run migrate it is going to put it back in?

Or should I just create another migration to delete that table?

What is the recommended way?

Thanks

Comment: Delete the migration and delete the table from the database?

Comment: @chris342423 Never do that if you work in a team !

Comment: @Alexandre Butynski He/she obviously isn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on your working conditions.

**Case 1 : you work alone or  you have not already pushed your modifications**

You just have to rollback the migration and then delete the migration file.

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
rm ./app/database/migrations/name_of_the_migration_file.php
```

**Case 2 : you work in a team**

In this case, one of your teammates could have already pulled and executed the migration. If you revert and delete it, he will not be able to delete the table easily.

Then you have to create an other migration to delete the table. This one should be the exact opposite of the previous one.

```
php artisan migrate::make revertTableCreation
```

Remember that the first goal of the migration system is to make team work and deployment easy by always keep consistent the code and the database.